# scalability - Calculate load for performance testing from requirements

Tags: performance-testing, system-design, requirements, system-requirements

Suppose we have an API endpoint that will receive 100 Million requests a year and suppose our application needs to have at least 95% of those requests handled with less than 30ms. Is there a model to calculate what will be the load for the performance test that can make these tests check if the current system can meet those requirements?

With load, I mean, for instance: in the test, we need to do `x` parallel requests and have `q`% of them with less than `t` ms.

Answer (score 0):

The "model" depends on your application usage patterns, i.e.

- whether it is used 24x7 or rather during business hours
- are there any [spikes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Spike_testing)
- is the load distributed evenly
- what is the logic behind different API endpoints if you have > 1 because `/health` or `/status` will be very fast and some wildcard search or bulk edit operation will be much longer

In general 100 million requests / year is not that big amount,

- 100 000 000 / 365 ~ 274 000 requests per day
- 274 000 / 24 ~ 11500 requests per hour
- 11500 / 3600 ~ **3 requests per second**

So you can use any [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools) which supports:

- [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP)
- including the ability to add [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
- including the ability to report [percentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile)
- including the ability to apply [pass/fail criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)) so the test execution could be marked as failed if response time exceeds acceptable